# Is *Petrificus Totalus* effect to lock the muscles or merely prevent their neural control?

Tags: harry-potter

While answering [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24566/basilisk-petrification-in-harry-potter-what-happens), one of the comments mentioned *Petrificus Totalus*, and I realized we don't actually know how exactly it effects the body (on a muscular or neural level).

Is the effect of *Petrificus Totalus* to lock the muscles or merely prevent their neural control?

**In other words, can another person easily move the body parts of someone hit with *Petrificus Totalus*, as they would a normal person?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the effects imparted upon Neville in the Philosopher's Stone, it appears to cause a near complete muscular lock (all but the eyes autonomic actions such as breathing and heart beating), forcing the arms to extend flat against the body and the legs to extend and press together.

> Neville’s arms snapped to his sides. His legs sprang together. His
>   whole body rigid, he swayed where he stood and then fell flat on
>   his face, stiff as a board. Hermione ran to turn him over. Neville’s jaws were jammed together so he couldn’t speak. Only his eyes were moving, looking at them in horror.

The alternative to a muscular/neurological affect would be that the target is "wrapped" in some force, similar to being immobilized in a tightly bound invisible blanket. But there doesn't seem to be evidence to indicate which it may be.

-EDIT-

The effects Harry suffers in Half-Blood Prince run somewhat contrary to Neville's reaction. From Harry's point of view he was paralyzed, unable to move any muscles. Indeed, rather than stiffening like Neville, Harry's body remained in the position it was in when he was hit with the spell, as thought it was froze, or locked, in place.

> ‘Petrificus Totalus!’
>   Without warning, Malfoy pointed his wand at Harry, who was instantly paralysed. As though in slow motion, he toppled out of the luggage rack and fell, with an agonising, floor-shaking crash, at Malfoy’s feet, the Invisibility Cloak trapped beneath him, his whole body revealed with his legs still curled absurdly into the cramped kneeling position. He couldn’t move a muscle; he could only gaze up at Malfoy, who smiled broadly.

So I propose that the Pretrificus Totalus spell works in two parts. It immobilizes the targets body with an invisible force and it also prevents them from making any voluntary muscle movements, which would indicate some kind of neurological component.

-EDIT2-

An alternative to what I've suggested, @GorchestopherH posits that the target is afflicted with a full body joint lock.

In summary, the net effect of *Petrificus Totalus* would be the stiffening of the body such that it would be extremely difficult to impossible for someone to reposition the limbs of a person immobilized by such a sell (mileage may vary; Hagrid may have an easier time of it than first year Harry, for example).

Comment: So, your answer to my **bold** question is "no" - e.g. Malfoy woudln't be able to move Harry's legs either?

Comment: @DVK Since falling out of a luggage rack did not move Harry's legs, I would assume Draco could not, without evidence to the contrary.

Comment: Consider that "cutting off" neural control to a muscle makes it go limp, not lock. Contrary to the question's stipulation, I believe the spell makes your joints lock, which is why you can move your eyes, breathe, etc.

Comment: @Xantec - makes sense. Could you elaborate that in the answer?

Comment: @GorchestopherH Did you want to make your own answer with that? I feel more that it is a neural condition, otherwise Harry would have said he couldn't move his limbs, rather than couldn't move a muscle.

Comment: @Xantec What constitutes "moving a muscle"? Relaxing or flexing it? Consider that if your joints are locked the endpoints of the muscle do not change, just the amount of flex they are *attempting*. Besides, he can breathe, move his eyes. Neville couldn't talk because of his *jaw*. Not tongue. To make your muscles keep your joints at the same angles with fabricated neural impulses would be incredibly complicated. First, you'd have to isolate the muscles controlling non-organs, then keep their electrical impulses continual and perfectly balanced against themselves and external forces.

Comment: @Xantec As far as the question is concerned, it's the same answer as yours. I just disagree that it's "neural" as the neural answer is by and far the most complicated/strained explanation.

Comment: @GorchestopherH I wasn't trying to suggest that the spell caused the body to immobilized through special manipulation of the muscles.  I was offering that the body was held in placed with magic *and* the target was affected with a form of muscular paralysis (essentially a full body [neuromuscular-blocker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuromuscular_blocker)).

Comment: @Xantec You said the body would remain rigid. A neuro-muscular blocker would cause the muscle to go limp, and someone would easily be able to manipulate your pose.

Comment: @GorchestopherH I said the body would be held in place with magic (not beyond the realm of possibility in HP) in addition to the person losing all voluntary muscle control.

Comment: @Xantec So the spell locks the body in place (which is what I'm saying happens), then, as a bonus, cuts off your neurons? Seems un-necessary/un-documented. I'll discuss it in chat if you want, but the neural half to that seems unimportant.